# how to use GameCenterManager in multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, gamekit

I would like to be able to add a score, in a different view controller then the main.  So what is the best way to replace self in this call?

`[self.gameCenterManager reportScore: self.currentScore forCategory:self.currentLeaderBoard];`

I thought about passing it in to the view controller, but it is the third view controller, so i would need to pass it twice, feels wrong to me.

I thought about a NSManagedObjectContext, but then I saw in the sample has GameCenterManagerDelegate.

Is there a way to use that anywhere in the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out GKTapper to see this, but the VC that you call that function from should have a GameCenterManager declared.

Then your call will work, check out GKTapper.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I have seen GKTapper, what I need to know, is how to make the call in another view controller, not hte original one.